# How to view c-message from azure service queue in Python

Tags: python, azure, servicebus

I am using Azure service bus to view message contents of a messages sent from an service bus service.

I am using the `message.get_message()` command and it returns a c message as specified in the documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/uamqp/uamqp.message.message?view=azure-python

Is there a way to view the contents of the c message?

```
<uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessage object at 0x0000000003180F50>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean about the contents of the c message?

I think the content of the c message you received is the date to send in the message. So according to the offical API reference [`Message class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/uamqp/uamqp.message.message?view=azure-python), you should use `message.get_data()` to get the `body` of the message to view its content, as the figure below.

[image]

Or just only to view it by `print(...)` like the sample code [`azure-uamqp-python/samples/sample_uamqp_receive_simple.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/blob/master/samples/sample_uamqp_receive_simple.py).

> ```
> message = uamqp.receive_message(uri, auth=plain_auth)
> print("Received: {}".format(message))
> ```

If your real intention is to parse the `uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessage` data structure of the `massage` to view the internal contents, you can refer to the SO thread [Parsing C Structs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596118/parsing-c-structs-in-python) with the source codes [`message.h`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-c/blob/master/inc/azure_uamqp_c/message.h) & [`message.c`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-c/blob/master/src/message.c) of [`Azure/azure-uamqp-c`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-c) and the Python wrapper code [`message.pyx`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/blob/2f60b23f4a0b2a764987ed972636ddb7657e07ef/src/message.pyx) to try to parse it.

After I reviewed them above, the core data structure of `uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessage` is as below.

> ```
> typedef struct MESSAGE_INSTANCE_TAG
> {
>     BODY_AMQP_DATA* body_amqp_data_items;
>     size_t body_amqp_data_count;
>     AMQP_VALUE* body_amqp_sequence_items;
>     size_t body_amqp_sequence_count;
>     AMQP_VALUE body_amqp_value;
>     HEADER_HANDLE header;
>     delivery_annotations delivery_annotations;
>     message_annotations message_annotations;
>     PROPERTIES_HANDLE properties;
>     application_properties application_properties;
>     annotations footer;
>     uint32_t message_format;
> } MESSAGE_INSTANCE;
> ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: great answer! thanks
quick update: the latest servicebus version v7.0.0 changes this a little bit - please take a look at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-python